# How to get the local current time in seconds since epoch in C++ (MSVS)?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I need the local (with timezone offset) current time in seconds since epoch. The following code looks a bit clumzy because it creates an intermediate temporary structure *tm* which is superfluous. Why do I have to get *time_t* then convert it to *tm* in order to return to *time_t*? Is there a better way?

```
time_t ct = time(0);
tm lct = tm();
localtime_s(&lct, &ct);
ct = _mkgmtime(&lct);
```

Comment: what type is `tm`  ?

Comment: in seconds since when? epoch?

Comment: @tobi303 [tm structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: But isn't time() already returns seconds since epoch? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/

Comment: time() returns time without timezone offset. I need time WITH timezone offset.

Comment: FWIW I did some research on this a while back and concluded what you have was the best cross-platform way of handling it.  That is, there's no simple `tzOffsetSecs()` type of method near as I can tell.  (Also, not sure why you're getting downvotes, seems like a legit question to me)

Comment: Thanks, Mark! It at least means that both my question and suggested approach have some sense )))

Comment: Sure thing... I should point out that the line `tm lct = tm();` is odd to me... it creates a tm on the stack then copies it to another tm on the stack.  It might get optimized out in release but think maybe you just want `struct tm lct;` there.

Comment: Yes, probably `tm lct;` is enough. I wanted to init the struct with zeros just to be on the safe side. May be `tm lct = { 0 };` is better.

Comment: Can you tell us what you want to do with this time-with-timezone-offset?  As I explain in my answer, it's a strange thing to use, and questionably useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the local time (with time zone and DST applied) in portable C, then yes, it's generally a two-step procedure: starting with your time-since-the-epoch, first call `localtime`, then do something with the resulting broken-down `struct tm`.  (Usually what I do next is call `strftime`.)

You can also call `ctime` to get a local time string directly.

The reason there are a lot of different function calls involved is that, unfortunately, there are several different time formats in use.  (And the reason for that is that dates and times are complicated!)  You can represent time as seconds-since-1970.  You can represent it as a `struct tm`.  You can represent it as a string (in one of several zillion formats).  In Unix and Linux, you can represent it as a `struct timeval` or a `struct timespec`.

But one thing there isn't a straightforward or standard way to do, as you've discovered, is get *local* time as seconds-since-1970.  But the reason for that is that it's not a very useful representation.  In general, there are two things you might want to do with a date/time value: (1) perform computations on it or (2) display it to the user.  If you want to display it to the user, you probably want to display it in local time, so there are lots of ways of converting to local time in human-readable format in any format you want.  (As I said, the usual way is to call `localtime`, then `strftime`.)  But if you want to perform computations, really the only way to do those is using seconds-since-1970 in UTC, because that makes all the other hairy problems go away.  How many days are there in the month?  Is it a leap year?  What time zone are we in?  Is daylight saving time in effect?

If you try to represent local time as seconds-since-1970, though, you're probably fibbing.  For example, right now, the time is 1460383736, which is 14:08:56 UTC.  Where I'm sitting, that's 10:08:56 EDT (U.S. Eastern time, DST in effect).  So I suppose I could say that's 1460369336 seconds since 1970, local time.  But, again where I'm sitting, 1460369336 seconds ago was not midnight on January 1, 1970 -- it was actually 11 pm on December 31, 1969.  It's off by an hour, and the reason is that DST was not in effect on January 1, 1970.

So, bottom line, I would encourage you to rethink the way you're handling local times, because while it's possible to compute this "seconds-since-1970 as local time" value, it's an odd thing to do, and it's likely to cause you various problems which will be much harder to work around than if you used a more straightforward scheme.

---

But, if you really want to, here are two ways you might be able to determine the offset between UTC and local time, without calling `gmtime` or `_mkgmtime`:

1. Call `localtime`, and look at the `tm_gmtoff` field.  (Unfortunately, this field is nonstandard, and not present on all systems.)
2. Call the obsolete `ftime` function, and look at the `timezone` field of `struct timeb`.  (Here there are several gotchas: not only is `ftime` obsolete and nonstandard, but the `timezone` field is in *minutes*, and it's positive for zones west of Greenwich, while `tm_gmtoff` is negative.)

But, anyway, those would more or less directly give you the number to add to or subtract from your UTC seconds-since-1970 value to get "local" seconds-since-1970.

Comment: In fact I want to serialize it and pass it to the web-server. And on the server side I need to know the LOCAL current date/time of the request, not UTC. And, yes, I know I can pass it as a string: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'. Just wanted to know is there a shorter way. It appears I have to deserialize the date from an integer to a struct in order to serialize it back to an integer or to a string... Not very efficient.

Comment: @MikeSiomkin Got it.  And I gather you don't want to pass it from the client to the server as a UTC time and have the server convert it to local, because that would use the server's time zone, not the client's.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thre's no simple built in way to do it because it may lead to an error if DST/time zone changed since 1970 in the place where the program runs.

Comment: @MikeSiomkin Right.  And even if the time zone never changes, if there's DST, that part of the offset is always going to change twice per year!

Comment: "And I gather you don't want to pass it from the client to the server as a UTC time and have the server convert it to local, because that would use the server's time zone, not the client's" - Yes. Probably passing date/time as a string will make the code clearer and unambiguous.

Comment: I know just what you mean about having to fiddle with the time.  Several years ago, I was given the task of converting the RTC (where 0 was midnight, jan 1, 2000) to a correctly displayed current time in human readable format, allowing for the current time zone, DST, etc. I spent 4 MONTHS on that task (the spaghetti code I was given, to modify, didn't help any)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this computation using the C++11/14 `<chrono>` library plus this [free, open-source timezone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) to do the conversion to local time.

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto now = floor<seconds>(system_clock::now());
    auto s = current_zone()->to_local(now) - local_days{1970_y/jan/1};
    cout << s.count() << '\n';
}
```

You first discover your current IANA timezone with `current_zone()`.  Then you get the current time with `system_clock::now()` and truncate it to `seconds`.  Next you can convert that to your local time, and then subtract the result from any epoch you desire (1970-01-01 in this example).

The result is of type `std::chrono::seconds`.

All this being said, I share the same reservations about doing this as described in [Steve Summit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36550990/576911).

If you instead decide to represent the timestamp as a string, that is also easily done:

```
auto now = make_zoned(current_zone(), floor<seconds>(system_clock::now()));
auto str = format("%F %T %z", now);
```

`str` has type `std::string`.  This just output for me:

```
2016-04-11 11:42:50 -0400
```

which is my current local time (truncated to seconds), and my current local UTC offset.

If in the future you decide that seconds-precision is too coarse, you can easily change the above code to any other precision by just changing one line:

```
floor<milliseconds>(system_clock::now());
```

and now the contents of `str` would look like:

```
2016-04-11 11:42:50.368 -0400
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I thought there was a one-line solution. The c++11 version is hardly simpler than my initial code. And my project is in MSVS 2010, so I don't have c++11. I hoped that even C was enough for such a simple task. But as Steve said there are some problems with this approach.

Comment: @MikeSiomkin:  Yeah, nobody has tried to run this on MSVS 2010 and I wouldn't hold my breath on that one.  Fwiw, I actually did write the first bit of code as a one-liner, but the column width was a bit much, and it was harder to read. :-)